# How to iterate through two numpy arrays of different dimensions

Tags: arrays, numpy, keras

I am working with the MNIST dataset, `x_test` has dimension of (10000,784) and `y_test` has a dimension of (10000,10). I need to iterate through each sample of these two numpy arrays at the same time as I need to pass them individually to `score.evaluate()`

I tried `nditer`, but it throws an error saying operands could not be broadcasted together since hey have different shape.

```
    score=[]
    for x_sample, y_sample in np.nditer ([x_test,y_test]):
         a=x_sample.reshape(784,1)
         a=np.transpose(a)
         b=y_sample.reshape(10,1)
         b=np.transpose(b)
         s=model.evaluate(a,b,verbose=0)
         score.append(s)
```

Comment: Probably you are extracting `X_test` and `y_test` wrongly as they should have the same length. Please add your code where you get `X_test` and `y_test`.

Comment: How do you expect to iterate through 2 things of different size?  It doesn't make sense. One will run out of items before the other.

Comment: I have edited the question. There was typo

Comment: You need to include the full error traceback, as your question stands now, it is not clear to me what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that what you are actually trying to do here is to get the individual loss per sample in your test set, here is a way to do it (in your approach, even if you get past the iteration part, you will have issues with `model.evaluate`, which was not designed for *single* sample pairs)...

To make the example reproducible, here I also assume we have first run the [Keras MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py)  for only 2 epochs; so, the shape of our data is:

```
x_test.shape
# (10000, 28, 28, 1)

y_test.shape
# (10000, 10)
```

Given that, here is a way to get the individual loss per sample:

```
from keras import backend as K

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_test = y_test.astype('float32') # necessary, as y_pred.dtype is 'float32'
y_test_tensor = K.constant(y_test)
y_pred_tensor = K.constant(y_pred)
g = K.categorical_crossentropy(target=y_test_tensor, output=y_pred_tensor)

ce = K.eval(g)  # 'ce' for cross-entropy
ce
# array([1.1563368e-05, 2.0206178e-05, 5.4946734e-04, ..., 1.7662416e-04,
#        2.4232995e-03, 1.8954457e-05], dtype=float32)

ce.shape
# (10000,)
```

i.e. `ce` now contains what the `score` list in your question was supposed to contain.

For **confirmation**, let's calculate the loss for all test samples using `model.evaluate`:

```
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
# Test loss: 0.050856544668227435
```

and again manually, averaging the values of the `ce` we have just calculated:

```
import numpy as np

log_loss = np.sum(ce)/ce.shape[0]
log_loss
# 0.05085654296875
```

which, although not exactly equal (due to different numeric precision involved in the two ways of calculation), they are *practically* equal indeed:

```
log_loss == score[0]
# False

np.isclose(log_loss, score[0])
# True
```

Now, the adaptation of this to your own case, where the shape of `x_test` is `(10000, 784)`, is arguably straighforward...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing between training features and testing labels. The training set has 60,000 samples and the test set has 10,000 samples (that is, your `x_test` should be of dimension `(10000,784)`). Make sure you have download all the correct data, and don't mix up training data with testing data.

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/